# Trouble debugging a getJSON call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Rails app where I have a controller that returns JSON data:

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render :html => data }
   format.json { render :json => data.to_json }
 end
```

If I load this via the browser all is good.

I have a simple form where I am trying to validate the data entered from the JSON look up.  For now I am stuck at getting the JSON call to work.

Here is my JS (coffee script):

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#validate-data').click ->
    alert "hello!"
    $.getJSON '/mycontroller/data/myparameter', (data) ->
       obj = data
       msg = []
       for i of obj
         msg.push i + ' = ' + obj[i]
       alert msg.join('\n')
      return
    return
  return
```

When I click my validate button I get the `hello!` pop-up then after a bit of a pause I get a pop-up with `0 = [object Object]`.

My http call results in data like this:

```
[ { "query": "myparameter", "response": { "status": "ok", "err": [], etc...
```

I got the impression that after the getJSON call the data was parsed and you could just call `alert data.response.status` and you would get a pop-up `"ok"`

I suspect I am missing something obvious or trivial here or I do not have a grasp on this at all.

Comment: It seems you are iterating over data wrong. Which part of the `data` you want to retrieve ?

Comment: I added that for i loop from another post I saw to try and just confirm I am actually getting data back from my JSON request.  For example I was trying to just get that "status": "ok" to display.  I can force the result to be "status": "fail" to confirm it's working.

Comment: So what is the issue you now have ?

Comment: If I add `alert data.response.status` nothing happens.  Should that not work if my JSON is in fact returning data?

Comment: You have an array as I see. do `data[0].response.status`

Comment: Yup that did the trick. Add that as an answer and I will accept it. Is there a reason that does not come back as a regular object or does getJSON always return an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your question mentioned `data`, you have a hash inside an array.

```
[ { "query": "myparameter", "response": { "status": "ok", "err": [
```

You are accessing it wrong, that is why you are not getting the output as you expected it to do. You must do `data[0].response.status` which is the result you want to access as you said in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349495/trouble-debugging-a-getjson-call#comment54495621_33349495).